# How to export rendered Highchart chart as a pdf/png/jpeg in a Phonegap application?

Tags: javascript, cordova, highcharts, phonegap-plugins, canvg

I am trying to use

```
chart.exportChart({
  type: 'application/pdf',
  filename: 'my-pdf'
});
```

in a Phonegap application with no success, although all is working fine in the browser.

My Problem:

I want to attach the rendered chart as a pdf/png/jpeg in the iOS email client. How is it possible to save the downloaded content using `chart.exportChart` or any other way to the iOS Application Sandbox? Should I give the App Sandbox path in the `filename` key of the `chart.exportChart` method?

**Here is wat i tried:**(I am on cordova-1.6.1.js)

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFileSys, fail);


function fail() {

}

function gotFileSys(fileSystem) {
    chart.exportChart({
       type: 'application/pdf',
    filename: fileSystem.root.fullPath+"/my-pdf"
    });
}
```

The above dosen't work and console says-

> [INFO] Error in success callback: File1 = TypeError: 'undefined' is
>   not a function

PS: The way I tried is  an act of Desperation :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do it like this-

```
canvg(document.getElementById('canvas'), chart.getSVG());
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas") ; 
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""); //img is base64 encoded and can be persisted in the App Sandbox.
```

Will need to write a PhoneGap plugin and use [Matt's Category](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) to convert base64 encoded `img` into an image and save the binary in the App Sandbox.

**canvg** scripts are available at [here](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) and [here](http://www.phpied.com/rgb-color-parser-in-javascript/) shall be included in the markup as well.

Comment: I am also facing similar problem. Can you please share the code or something if you have found anything concrete. I have tried similar thing but didn't worked.